# Go's `NewSingleHostReverseProxy` is duplicating my query params when forwarding requests

Tags: go, google-sheets, proxy, reverse-proxy, http-proxy

Given the following handler:

```go
func handler(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    parsedURL, _ := url.Parse(request.URL.String())

    destinationURL := parsedURL.Query().Get("url")

    fmt.Println("Destination->", destinationURL)

    parsedDestinationURL, e := url.Parse(destinationURL)
    if e != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s", e)
    }

    fmt.Println("Parsed destination->", parsedDestinationURL)

    proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(parsedDestinationURL)

    proxy.Transport = DebugTransport{}

    request.URL.Host = parsedURL.Host
    request.URL.Scheme = parsedURL.Scheme
    request.Header.Set("X-Forwarded-Host", request.Header.Get("Host"))
    request.Host = parsedURL.Host

    response.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")

    proxy.ServeHTTP(response, request)
}
```

if I hit the endpoint it's serving like:

```
myurl.tld?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Fspreadsheets%2Fd%2FSKEET_KEY%2Fgviz%2Ftq%3Ftqx%3Dout%3Acsv%26sheet%3DMY_DATA%26range%3DA%3AC
```

(unescaped version for legibility:

```
myurl.tld?url=https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SHEET_KEY/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet=MY_DATA&range=A:C
```

)

I'm causing the proxy to hit "duplicate" my query parameters like:

```
Destination-> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SHEET_KEY/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv
Parsed destination-> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SHEET_KEY/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv
GET /spreadsheets/d/SHEET_KEY/gviz/tq/?tqx=out:csv&url=https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SHEET_KEY/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet=MY_DATA&range=A:C HTTP/1.1
Host: docs.google.com
User-Agent: xh/0.15.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
X-Forwarded-For: ::1
X-Forwarded-Host:
```

(taken from the logs printed in the aforementioned Go code).

You can clearly see the proxied requests looks like:
`GET /spreadsheets/d/SHEET_KEY/gviz/tq/?tqx=out:csv&url=https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SHEET_KEY/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet=MY_DATA&range=A:C HTTP/1.1`

I'm already escaping the content of the `url` query param, like
`https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Fspreadsheets%2Fd%2FSKEET_KEY%2Fgviz%2Ftq%3Ftqx%3Dout%3Acsv%26sheet%3DMY_DATA%26range%3DA%3AC`, so I guess it's not a matter of unescaped special characters.

How could I fix this unexpected behaviour?

Comment: Your URL is malformed. The destination url must be query encoded. Ask yourself: Where does the value of url end? Is tqx a query parameter if the endpoint you call or part of url? And: never ignore errors.

Comment: @Volker As I wrote, I'm already encoding my destination URL, so the complete request looks like: myurl.tld?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Fspreadsheets%2Fd%2FSKEET_KEY%2Fgviz%2Ftq%3Ftqx%3Dout%3Acsv%26sheet%3DMY_DATA%26range%3DA%3AC Is there another round of escaping I should do somewhere else? Ty for the patience and the kind advice.

Comment: Why are you using a ReverseProxy anway? You are _not_ using a reverse proxy. And the behaviour is expected from the documentation of go doc net/http/httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy: "NewSingleHostReverseProxy returns a new ReverseProxy that routes URLs to
    the scheme, host, and base path provided in target. If the target's path is
    "/base" and the incoming request was for "/dir", the target request will be
    for /base/dir."

Comment: Instead of creating a revproxy inside your handler you probably should set up _one_ ReverseProxy with and appropriate Director.

Comment: I've probably misunderstood the purpose of `NewSingleHostReverseProxy`. I just want to forward every and each request hitting my endpoint to the endpoint defined in the `url` part of the original query params. (Example example.net?url=https://example.com?a=1234 has to forward the request to https://example.com?a=1234, overwriting some headers as shown in the code above)

Comment: Yeah, seems so. Set up a ReverseProxy and do the URL stuff there in the Director.